# Kann man in einem E-Mail »Vielen für die Rückmeldung« statt »Vielen Dank für die Rückmeldung« sagen?

Tags: colloquial, letter

Wie schon geschrieben: Kann man einfach:

> Vielen für die Rückmeldung

ohne das Wort *Dank* sagen? Wird das umgangssprachlich auch auf der Straße benutzt, oder ist das nur in E-Mails erlaubt?

Comment: Das ist sehr schlechter Stil und sollte in keinem offiziellen oder förmlichen Rahmen verwendet werden! Unter guten Bekannten kann man so etwas schreiben und sagen, gerade letzteres kommt durchaus vor. Ich würde aber auch dort vom Gebrauch absehen, da, wie gesagt, es sehr schlechter Stil ist.

Comment: Nein! Das ist kein deutscher Satz und auch nicht umgangssprachlich.

Comment: If you have seen this in an email, it was probably just a typo, the word was omitted by accident.

Comment: Absolut einfach ein Schreibfehler.

Comment: Vielen Dank Leute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Einfache und kurze Antwort:

### NEIN

Das ist falsch.

Mir ist auch nicht bekannt, dass eine solche Formulierung umgangssprachlich Verwendung findet. Sie ist weder in E-Mails noch in anderen Textsorten üblich.

Comment: Solche Formulierungen gibt es umgangssprachlich durchaus: "Auf keinen [Fall]", "Guten [Appetit]",  "Ich mache mir heute einen ruhigen [Tag]" usw.

Comment: @RoyPJ: Wirklich? Wo? Wer sagt sowas?

Comment: Besonders die Formulierung "Guten" vor dem Essen ist zumindest hier (Raum Heidelberg) weit verbreitet und wird sowohl im privaten als auch geschäftlichen Bereich verwendet. "Auf keinen [Fall]" haben wir in unserer Jugend oft gesagt, auch heute höre ich das vereinzelt im Vorbeigehen. "[...] einen ruhigen [Tag]" ist hier auch weit verbreitet, ich meine sogar, es in einer Radiowerbung vor kurzem gehört zu haben.

Comment: @RoyPJ Du hast mit deinen Beispielen schon recht. Aber das sind m. E. alles Wendungen mit einen bzw. keinen. "Guten" kenne ich nur als "'nen Guten", also dir Kurzfassung "Ich wünsche einen guten Appetit!". Aber bei "Vielen Dank" gibt es keine Langfassung mit "einen".

Comment: Auslassungen gibt es im Alltag viele. "Guten" für "Guten Appetit" hört man genauso wie "Morgen" für "Guten Morgen". Dass "Vielen" für "Vielen Dank" nicht auftritt (oder bis heute nicht auftrat) liegt vermutlich ganz einfach daran, dass anders als bei "Guten Appetit" und "Guten Morgen" der Kontext so verschieden sein kann, dass er das fehlende Wörtchen nicht selbstverständlich ersetzt.

Comment: Habe ich auch alles schon gehört, aber selten. Geschrieben gesehen, noch seltener, wenn überhaupt. An den ungläubigen Rückmeldungen sieht man auch, wieso man es nicht tun sollte: Der Adressat sucht den Satz ab, was er bedeuten soll, und denkt unnötigerweise lange darüber nach, überlegt vielleicht sogar nachzufragen.